# How do I add a link to the drop down select option?

Tags: laravel

[This is an image of my drop down select showing islands e.g Maiana as parent and culprits as child e.g Batiboa Kumeto etc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCbzD.png)I just wondering to know how to  add a link in the select option and to pass the id to another form ?.

I tried to create a drop down shown in the image above

Maiana
    - Koriaue Miruango
    - Batiboa Kumeto

Abaiang
    - Erenawa Aeete

but what I can not achieve is to add a link 
to Koriaue Miruango,   - Batiboa Kumeto under Maiana Island, and the rest. Once one of the name e.g Batiboa Kumeto is clicked an id is passed to load another form.

appreciate your help

My Island Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Enforcement;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Island extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'islands';

    protected $fillable = ['island_name'];

    public function culprits(){
        return $this->hasMany(Culprit::class, 'island_id');
    }
 }
```

My Culprit Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Enforcement;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Culprit extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'culprits';
    protected $fillable =  ['island_id','first_name','last_name','age','home_island'];

   public function island(){
       return $this->belongsTo(Island::class, 'island_id');
   }

   public function crimes(){
       return $this->hasMany(Crime::class);
   }
}
```

My Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\Enforcement;
use App\Model\Enforcement\Culprit;
use App\Model\Enforcement\Island;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $islands = Island::with(['culprits'])->get();
       // $culprits = Culprit::get();

        // dd($islands, $culprits);


       return  view('backend.enforcement.admin.tests.show',compact('islands','culprits'));
}

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create($id)
    {
        $culprit = Culprit::findOrFail($id);
        $offences = Offence::pluck('name','id')->all();
        $fishedareas = Fishedarea::pluck('fishedarea_name','id')->all();

     return view('backend.enforcement.admin.tests.create',compact('culprit','offences','fishedareas'));
}
```

My Route

```
   Route::resource('/enforcements/tests', 'Frontend\Enforcement   \TestController');
  Route::get('/enforcements/tests/{id?}', 'Frontend\Enforcement\TestController@create')->name('tests.create');
```

My index view

```
<select data-placeholder="Select island" style="width:350px;"   class="chosen-select" tabindex="5">
<option value=""></option>
@foreach ($islands as $island)
        <optgroup value="{{$island->id}}" label="    {{$island->island_name}}">
        @foreach($island->culprits as $culprit)
        <option value = "{{$culprit->id}}"> {{$culprit->first_name}}<a  href="{{route('tests.create', $culprit->id)}}"> {{$culprit->last_name}}    </a></option>
        </optgroup>
        @endforeach
@endforeach
</select>
```

My Create Form

```
                       <div>

                        {!! Form::open(array('url' => route('tests.store'))) !!}
                        {!! Form::hidden('id', $culprit->id, old('id'), ['class' => 'form-control']) !!} 
                        {!! Form::label('offence_id','Offence Name')!!}
                        {!! Form::select('offence_id',['' => 'Choose Offence Type']+ $offences, null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
                        {!! Form::label('fishedarea_id','Fished Area')!!}
                        {!! Form::select('fishedarea_id',['' => 'Choose Fished Areas']+ $fishedareas, null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
                        {!! Form::label('crime_date','Date')!!}
                        {!! Form::date('crime_date',null,['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
                        {!! Form::label('remarks','Remarks')!!}
                        {!! Form::textarea('remarks',null,['class'=>'form-control'])!!}

                       </div>   


                       <div class="form-group">

                       <button class="btn btn-primary">Add New</button>

                       </div>

                        <div>

            {!! Form::close() !!}
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As  for know I did some trial and error experiment and come up with something like this that solves my issue. sure there is a better way from your end

```
<select name="forma"  data-placeholder="Select island" style="width:350px;"   class="chosen-select" tabindex="5" onchange="location =    this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
<option value=""></option>
@foreach ($islands as $island)
        <optgroup value="{{$island->id}}" label="{{$island->island_name}}">
        @foreach($island->culprits as $culprit)
        {{--<option value="{{route('tests.create', $culprit->id)}}">    {{$culprit->first_name}}  {{$culprit->last_name}}</option>--}}
        <option value="{{route('tests.create', $culprit->id)}}">
        <a href="{{route('tests.create', $culprit->id)}}">{{$culprit->first_name}}      {{$culprit->last_name}}</a>
       </option>
       </optgroup>
        @endforeach
@endforeach
</select>
```