# laravel redirect to page based on id from database is selected

Tags: php, laravel, database

I'm new to laravel And want help on how to do this!
goal: when I click on the city name from the select option it will route me to a page that has all villas in that city.

So I have the website controller as follows:

```
class WebsiteController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $users = Villa::with('City','Seller', 'Payment')->get();
      return view('website', compact('users'));
}
```

the website blade:

```
 <select class="form-select">
                      <option value=""  id="searchoption"> City </option>
                      @foreach($users as $villa )
              
                          <option id="searchoption" value="{{ $villa->City->id }}" >
                            {{ $villa->City->name }}
                          </option>
                  
                          
                          
                      @endforeach
 </select>
```

This code probably doesn't give me all cities' names based on id!
here villa model:

```
class Villa extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable=[
        "id", "title", "description", "price", "state", "status", "city_id", "seller_id", "payment_id", "created_at", "updated_at"
    ];
    public function City()
    {
        return $this -> hasOne(City::class,'id','city_id');
    }
    public function Seller()
    {
        return $this -> hasOne(Seller::class,'id','seller_id');
    }
    public function Payment()
    {
        return $this -> hasOne(Payment::class,'id','payment_id');
    }
}
```

and here's the route :

```
Route::get('/',[WebsiteController::class,'index'])->name('home.index');
```

I want a way when I click on the city select option to show me all cities' names based on id from the database cities table and when I select one to route me on a page that shows all villas in that city.

Comment: actually I want it to route when I click on search button

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54317528/how-do-i-add-a-link-to-the-drop-down-select-option)  might help you when selecting it but you have changed your question what you can do is make a post request form and while submitting the form you can pass the city id to a function and query all villa based on it then show the result on new page

Comment: @NishanTimsina could you show me some code, please?

Comment: writing code will takes me some time and i am currently bg but if you can navigate laravel code [this](https://github.com/Nisshan/Hotel-Booking/tree/master/resources/views/frontend/search) might help you to achieve something.